# erb: Using each_with_index on a link_to id string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How can I add the variable *i* in the id tag on link_to such as this:

```
<% @tips.each_with_index do |tip, i| %>
<%= link_to "Flag me", flag_path, method: :put, remote: true, id: "flag_<i goes here>" %>
<% end %>
```

When using an html code, I can just do this:

```
<a href="/path" id="flag_<%= i %>"> Flag me </a>
```

I am not sure how to insert a variable inside the erb id tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just regular ruby interpolation

```
id: "flag_#{i}"
```